# htaccess rewrite messing with jquery ajax url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I have rewritten my URLs from

> mysite.com/?a=QUERY_ONE&b=QUERY_TWO

to

> mysite.com/QUERY_ONE/QUERY_TWO

I have my ajax file on my root directory and when I pass a request I use:

> $.get('ajax-file.php', PARAMETERS, function (data) {});

But when someone visits **mysite.com/QUERY_ONE/**,

*QUERY_ONE* acts as a directory for which my ajax requests don't work because they cannot find "ajax-file.php" in *QUERY_ONE* directory.

How do I keep the ajax file in root directory and still access it?

Answer (score 1):

Add a `/` before the `ajax-file.php`:

```
$.get('/ajax-file.php', PARAMETERS, function (data) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just a while a go. I'm developing using my `localhost` and the problem was `.htaccess` is not allowing the `jquery` to be run. The solution I found for this is: reference your `jquery` from `jquery` repository itself and not in your local directory.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

more details of the solution is here:

> http://community.sitepoint.com/t/htaccess-file-stops-making-jquery-work/54654/11